# How to get rid of background color of Android Studio comments in dark theme?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I've installed Android Studio 2.1 and switched to the dark theme. How do I get rid of this background color? I can't seem to find it anywhere. I've changed all the background colors of comments but I can't seem to get rid of this:

[image]

The `Created by Can...` comment has a background like it's selected (of course it's not selected) and it's really disturbing my attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That background is actually warning highlight from code inspection. You can disable it by going to `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections`, where you can search for `Default File Template Usage` and uncheck it ([screenshot for help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdu8B.png)).